# MongooseError: Query was already executed: Todo.updateOne({ _id: new ObjectId("612df063a8f

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I updated mongoose to latest version (6.0.2) and now I'm recieving this error and crush the application whenever `.updateOne()` is executed. But object update inside the database. My code:

```js
async(req,res) => {
    await Todo.updateOne(
        {_id : req.params.id},
        {
            $set : {
                status : "inactive"
            }
        },
        (updateError) => {
            // if updateError exist
            if (updateError) {
                // print error
                printError(updateError);

                // response the error
                res.status(500).json({
                    error : "There was a Server Side Error!"
                });
            } else {
                // if error dose not exist
                // print message
                console.log("|===> ️  Data Was Updated successfully! ️ <====|\n");
                // response success
                res.json({
                    message : "Todo Was Update successfully!"
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Don't use callbacks with async/await

Comment: >>>> why and what to do in that case ???

Comment: because they cant be used both at the same time, use callback or await. If you need to catch error in async/await use try/catch block

Comment: >>>> thanks. it working now. but one more thing.when I insert data that time I use callback and await but this time it work well. just it not work update case.why it's happen ?

Answer (score 6):

Try to add .clone() to de updateOne function

```
async(req,res) => {
    await Todo.updateOne(
         {_id : req.params.id},
         {
              $set : {
                    status : "inactive"
              }
         },
         (updateError) => {
              // if updateError exist
              if (updateError) {
                    // print error
                    printError(updateError);

                    // response the error
                    res.status(500).json({
                         error : "There was a Server Side Error!"
                    });
              } else {
                    // if error dose not exist
                    // print message
                    console.log("|===> ️  Data Was Updated successfully! ️ <====|\n");
                    // response success
                    res.json({
                         message : "Todo Was Update successfully!"
                    });
              }
         }).clone();
    }
```

Latest version of mongoose not duplicate execution

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#duplicate-query-execution

Comment: this .clone(); work for me in query middle-ware too

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `async` syntax, put your code in `try/catch` blok:

```js
async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await Todo.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, { $set: { status: "inactive"}});
    res.status(200).json({message: "Todo Was Update successfully!"});
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({error:'There was a Server Side Error!'})
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your async/await should look like this:

```js
async (req,res) => {
  try {
      const result = await Todo.updateOne(
          {_id : req.params.id},
          {
              $set : {
                  status : "inactive"
              }
          },
          );
      }
      console.log('success', result)
      res.json({message: "Todo Was Update successfully!", result })
  } catch (err) {
     console.log('error', err)
     res.status(500).json({error:'There was a Server Side Error!'})
  }
}
```